# Reverse each row of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I would like to create a reverse array of a 2D array, such that each row of the original array is reversed (no reversing of columns).

Meaning, If this is the input array:

> 1 2 3
>   3 2 1
>   2 1 3

Than this is the desired output:

> 3 2 1
>   1 2 3
>   3 1 2

The problem is that the output I'm getting is completely wrong.

This is my code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] forward = { 
                { 1, 2, 3 }, 
                { 3, 2, 1 }, 
                { 2, 1, 3 } 
            };

        int rows = forward.length;
        int cols = forward[0].length;
        int[][] reverse = new int[rows][cols];

        for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = cols - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                reverse[rows - 1 - i][cols - 1 - j] = forward[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print(reverse[i][j]);
                if (j < cols - 1)
                    System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What code do you have so far?

Comment: no one is going to write code for you.

Comment: please explain your problem properly... i can't understand what you have as input and what you want as an output

Comment: You still haven't asked a question (something that ends with `?`) or shown your code...

Comment: What's the logic? We can't understand what is the desired result if say the rows had 4 elements each. And most important, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry To All For Trouble Actually. I Am A New User Of Stack-overflow And This Is A My First Question so i do some mistake

Comment: I wan a  2d arrays printing backwards

Comment: We don't do code writing requests on Stack Overflow. But we can help find and correct problems with existing code so [[edit]] your question and include your attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: Also since you are new on Stack Overflow you should read [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) articles like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic where you will learn that "3. Questions asking for homework help must include a *summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem*, and a *description of the difficulty you are having solving it*."

Comment: See also: [How do I ask good questions?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i was trying to write code but i do not  do it   can any body help me  in post my code

Comment: just paste the code. we can re-edit it to make it look ok. Moreover, explain what it is you're trying to achieve. one example is not enough.

Comment: hi Pshemo  Please don't voting to close this question as off-topic .i allready told you i am  new user of this side and i have not  any  experience about how to write Question ...

Comment: Don't treat voting personally. We don't judge person but question and since it wasn't anything more than "I want to do ..." without clear problem it wasn't on-topic on Stack Overflow so I cast my vote accordingly. Now since your question was improved I will retract my vote when you explain how your code doesn't work (we know what you want to achieve, but you still didn't explain what you get instead, in other words what is the problem).

Comment: Could you reverse the array *in place*. i.e. do you need the original array?

Comment: So you have posted code now but still lack to explain what the code does and how it’s different to what you expected.

Comment: yes I Want a reverse the array in place.

Comment: This obviously is his first question here. Be a little gentler please..

Comment: If you're wanting to reverse in place, then (1) you don't need `reverse` which considerably simplifies things. And (2) you iterate through and reverse each row in turn. To do that, write a loop that swaps the first element with the last one, then the second element with the penultimate one, etc.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to say that you want to reverse the array in place. That changes (and simplifies) the algorithm considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to print reverse every row of my array

Problem is that in your loops you are reversing not only columns, but also rows

```
reverse[rows - 1 - i][cols - 1 - j] = forward[i][j];
```

which results in 180 degree rotation of array.

If you want to only reverse content of row it means that you want to reverse order of their columns (which you already handled). So instead of

```
reverse[rows - 1 - i][cols - 1 - j] = forward[i][j];
```

use

```
reverse[i][cols - 1 - j] = forward[i][j];// change only columns  
//      ^--------------------------^     // rows should stay the same
```

---

BTW you don't have to loop over rows or columns with reverse order

```
for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

simple forward for-loop will also do the trick and will be more readable

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
```

Comment: It's Work my problem is solved Tnx  Pshemo

Answer (score 1):

Added the following line in your reversing loop:

```
System.out.println("reverse[" + (rows - 1 - i) + "][" + (cols - 1 - j) + "] = forward[" + i + "][" + j + "]");
```

And this is what i got:

> reverse[0][0] = forward[2][2]
>   reverse[0][1] = forward[2][1]
>   reverse[0][2] = forward[2][0]
>   reverse[1][0] = forward[1][2]
>   reverse[1][1] = forward[1][1]
>   reverse[1][2] = forward[1][0]
>   reverse[2][0] = forward[0][2]
>   reverse[2][1] = forward[0][1]
>   reverse[2][2] = forward[0][0]

---

What you are doing is mixing the rows.

Your reverse loop should go over the same row number for `forward` and `reverse`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = cols - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        reverse[i][cols - 1 - j] = forward[i][j];
    }
}
```

This way we get the desired behavior:

> reverse[0][0] = forward[0][2]
>   reverse[0][1] = forward[0][1]
>   reverse[0][2] = forward[0][0]
>   reverse[1][0] = forward[1][2]
>   reverse[1][1] = forward[1][1]
>   reverse[1][2] = forward[1][0]
>   reverse[2][0] = forward[2][2]
>   reverse[2][1] = forward[2][1]
>   reverse[2][2] = forward[2][0]